# Parse Firestore array field by object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

This is my object `orders` where `productNodeIds` is an array.

```
var orders = {
    userName:"",
    userPhoneNumber: "",
    billingAddress: "",
    shippingAddress: "",
    deliveryOptions: "",
    isDelivered: "",
    productNodeIds: [],
    timestamp: ""
}
```

And this is how I am parsing them from Firestore

```
function fetchRequest() {
    var table = document.getElementById("outputTableID");
    if (table.rows.length > 2) {
        resetTable(table);
    }
    firestore.collection(parentNode).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      // console.log('${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}');
      var productItem = Object.create(orders);
      productItem.nodeId = doc.data().nodeId;
      productItem.userName = doc.data().userName;
      productItem.userPhoneNumber = doc.data().userPhoneNumber;
      productItem.billingAddress = doc.data().billingAddress;
      productItem.shippingAddress = doc.data().shippingAddress;
      productItem.deliveryOptions = doc.data().deliveryOptions;
      productItem.isDelivered = doc.data().isDelivered;
      productItem.productNodeIds = doc.data().productNodeIds;
      productItem.timestamp = doc.data().timestamp;

      var row = table.insertRow(2);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
      var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
      var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
      var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
      var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
      var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
      cell1.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell2.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell3.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell4.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell5.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell6.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell7.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell8.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell9.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';

      cell1.innerHTML = productItem.timestamp;
      cell2.innerHTML = productItem.userName;
      cell3.innerHTML = productItem.userPhoneNumber;
      cell4.innerHTML = productItem.billingAddress;
      cell5.innerHTML = productItem.shippingAddress;
      cell6.innerHTML = productItem.deliveryOptions;
      cell7.innerHTML = productItem.isDelivered;
      appendProductNodeListButtonOnCell(cell8, productItem);
      appendDeleteButtonOnCell(cell9, productItem);
    });
  });
}
```

But my `productItem.productNodeIds = doc.data().productNodeIds;` return a bunch of string instead of array. So in this capacity how could I get the array?

orderList.js:

```
//var productTitle = document.forms["product"]["productTitle"].value;
//document.getElementById('outPut').innerHTML = doc.data().title;
// console.log('${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}');
window.onload = function() {
  fetchRequest();
};

var parentNode = "orders";

function fetchRequest() {
    var table = document.getElementById("outputTableID");
    if (table.rows.length > 2) {
        resetTable(table);
    }
    firestore.collection(parentNode).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      // console.log('${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}');
      var productItem = Object.create(orders);
      productItem.nodeId = doc.data().nodeId;
      productItem.userName = doc.data().userName;
      productItem.userPhoneNumber = doc.data().userPhoneNumber;
      productItem.billingAddress = doc.data().billingAddress;
      productItem.shippingAddress = doc.data().shippingAddress;
      productItem.deliveryOptions = doc.data().deliveryOptions;
      productItem.isDelivered = doc.data().isDelivered;
      productItem.productNodeIds = doc.data().productNodeIds;
      productItem.timestamp = doc.data().timestamp;

      var row = table.insertRow(2);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
      var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
      var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
      var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
      var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
      var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
      cell1.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell2.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell3.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell4.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell5.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell6.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell7.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell8.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';
      cell9.style.cssText = 'font-size: 12px;';

      cell1.innerHTML = productItem.timestamp;
      cell2.innerHTML = productItem.userName;
      cell3.innerHTML = productItem.userPhoneNumber;
      cell4.innerHTML = productItem.billingAddress;
      cell5.innerHTML = productItem.shippingAddress;
      cell6.innerHTML = productItem.deliveryOptions;
      cell7.innerHTML = productItem.isDelivered;
      appendProductNodeListButtonOnCell(cell8, productItem);
      appendDeleteButtonOnCell(cell9, productItem);
    });
  });
}

function resetTable(table) {
    // for removing all cell but top 2, I use i > 1. For top 3 it would be i > 2
    for(var i = table.rows.length - 1; i > 1; i--) {
        table.deleteRow(i);
    }
}

function appendProductNodeListButtonOnCell(cell, productItem) {
    // Add delete button
    var loadProductNodeButton = document.createElement('button');
    loadProductNodeButton.id = "::button";
    loadProductNodeButton.className = "buttonGotoProduct";
    loadProductNodeButton.innerHTML = "Product List";
    cell.appendChild(loadProductNodeButton);
    loadProductNodeButton.onclick = function() {
    gotoProductNodeList(productItem);
    };
}

function gotoProductNodeList(productItem) {
  // productList
  //productNodeIds
  localStorage.setItem("productNodeIds", productItem.productNodeIds);
  window.location.href = "productList.html";

}

function appendDeleteButtonOnCell(cell, productItem) {
    // Add delete button
    var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.id = "::button";
    deleteButton.className = "buttonDelete";
    deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete Item";
    cell.appendChild(deleteButton);
    deleteButton.onclick = function() {
    deleteItem(productItem);
    };
}

function deleteItem(productItem) {
  if (confirm('Do you want to delete the order from "' + productItem.userName+'"?\n(Press Ok if you are Sure.)')) {
    document.getElementById("loaderId").style.visibility = 'visible';
    //1. Delete the item from product node
    deleteOrderFromOrderNode(productItem).then(
      function(result) {
        if (result == "success") {
          alert("Document successfully deleted!");
          fetchRequest();
          document.getElementById("loaderId").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
      }).catch(
      function(error) {
        alert(error);
      })
  } else {
    // Do nothing!
  }
}
```

orderListObjects:

```
var orders = {
    userName:"",
    userPhoneNumber: "",
    billingAddress: "",
    shippingAddress: "",
    deliveryOptions: "",
    isDelivered: "",
    productNodeIds: [],
    timestamp: ""
}
```

productList:

```
var productNodeIds;
window.onload = function() {
  productNodeIds = localStorage.getItem("productNodeIds")
  console.log(productNodeIds);
  fetchRequest();
};

var parentNode = "album";

function fetchRequest() {
    var table = document.getElementById("outputTableID");
  if (table.rows.length > 2) {
        resetTable(table);
    }

  var i;
  var nodeId;

  for (i = 0; i < productNodeIds.length; i++) {
    nodeId = productNodeIds[i];

    firestore.collection(parentNode).orderBy("serialNo").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        if (doc.data().nodeId == nodeId) {
          var productAlbumItem = Object.create(productAlbum);
          productAlbumItem.nodeId = doc.id;
          productAlbumItem.parentProductCategory = doc.data().parentProductCategory;
          productAlbumItem.serialNo = doc.data().serialNo;
          productAlbumItem.title = doc.data().title;
          productAlbumItem.price = doc.data().price;
          productAlbumItem.discountedPrice = doc.data().discountedPrice;
          productAlbumItem.discountPercentage = doc.data().discountPercentage;
          productAlbumItem.inventory = doc.data().inventory;
          productAlbumItem.imgName = doc.data().imgName;
          productAlbumItem.imgUrl = doc.data().imgUrl;
          productAlbumItem.imgStorageRef = doc.data().imgStorageRef;
          productAlbumItem.timestamp = doc.data().timestamp;
          productAlbumItem.description = doc.data().description;
          productAlbumItem.mostPopularBoolValue = doc.data().mostPopularBoolValue;
          productAlbumItem.newlyAddedBoolValue = doc.data().newlyAddedBoolValue;
          productAlbumItem.discountedBoolValue = doc.data().discountedBoolValue;
          productAlbumItem.bannerValue = doc.data().bannerValue;

          var row = table.insertRow(2);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
          var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
          var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
          cell1.innerHTML = productItem.title;
          cell2.innerHTML = productItem.price;
          cell3.innerHTML = productItem.discountedPrice;
          cell4.innerHTML = productItem.discountPercentage;
          cell5.innerHTML = productItem.inventory;
          appendImageOnCell(cell6, productItem.imgUrl);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

function appendImageOnCell(cell, productAlbumItem) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.id = "::img";
    img.style.cssText = 'max-width:150px; max-height:150px;';
    img.src = productAlbumItem.imgUrl;
    img.onload = function() { //check to make sure that the image has loaded
            cell.appendChild(img);
    };
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to show the exact contents of the actual document you're receiving.  The document might actually contain an array of strings, but we can't see that.  Please also be clear about what you're observing.  "A bunch of string" is not a very helpful description.  In general, you shouldn't have to do anything special to deal with array type fields - they will simply show up as arrays in JavaScript.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for your comment. I have updated my question. Please take have a look.

Comment: I don't get it, you are actually getting an array of ids. Can you explain which is the real problem? Do you want the real producstNode entities? @Tulon

Comment: @chfumero Right now I am getting two separate values like these`5026....896, 714.....049`. But I want two string arrays like this `"5026....896", "714.....049"`.

Comment: @chfumero Later when I count the `productNodeIds` it is returned 31, instead of 2.

Comment: @Tulon Can you post a console.log of the response of the query? Console.log(doc.data())

Comment: OK, please wait

Comment: @chfumero Here it is: `502646057518896,714399761253049` and
productNodeIds.length `31`

Comment: My concern is, I have declared it as an array on my object like this `productNodeIds: [],`, but when I parse the data (`productItem.productNodeIds = doc.data().productNodeIds;`) why it is not inserted into `productItem.productNodeIds` like the array.? Instead an string?

Comment: You can check (as debug purpose) that ```productNodeIds``` is indeed a string (```typeof(prodcutNodeIds) === 'string'``` or ```Array.isArray(productNodeIds) === false```). In which case you check _why_ and if that is a wanted design on your field, you can just ```productItem.productNodeIds = productNodeIds.split(',')```

Comment: There's really not enough information here to understand what's wrong. Please show the code that illustrates that the length of the array is 31 instead of 2, and be very specific about what is not working the way you expect.  We should be able to see everything you're seeing.  Also please read this to help construct a mcve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson I have added the 3 files, now you can check.

Comment: @grodzi actually I don't want to go for the split. It would be better If I get the array in my `productNodeIds` as it is.

Comment: I am new in javascript. So sorry for my poor coding.

Comment: this is where I was printing.  `for (i = 0; i < productNodeIds.length; i++) {
    nodeId = productNodeIds[i];`

Comment: @Tulon You have a lot going on there. I don't think that this is a firebase array issue. You should debug your code and check better where the problem is. In your last file, you are using a reference to an undefined variable `productItem `.

Comment: Please ignore the last `firestore.collection(parentNode).` part. I am stuck with the array printing issue. Those codes will be changed.

Comment: @Tulon it is a string because you are using localstorage-get to retrieve those values. Try productNodeIds = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("productNodeIds")) and remember saving it using localStorage.setItem('productNodeIds', JSON.stringify(nodeArray))

Comment: getting error in here `localStorage.getItem.set('productNodeIds', JSON.stringify) `

Comment: Sorry, comment updated. This could help https://blog.logrocket.com/the-complete-guide-to-using-localstorage-in-javascript-apps-ba44edb53a36/.

Comment: @chfumero Thanks a lot for your help man. Yes, this is where I was stuck. :) :) :) Please post it as an answer. I am going to accept it with an upvote. O:)

Comment: Can you guys give me one more direction here? As you can see I am looping through my Firestore in `productList` file. I think it is not the right way to fetch data from Firestore through a loop, How could I fetch Firestore inside a loop? Any suggestion or guidance please? Thanks

Comment: You are fetching the items from a collection correctly. You are currently doing one query and iterating on the response. The official docs have good examples that illustrate how to perform these kinds of operations. Good luck :). https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data